# Does math.net numerics have a matrix object that can return a value from a matrix based on input values?

Tags: math.net

I am currently using a third-party decision engine for some decision rules.  I would like to replace that with c# code but have no idea how to process a matrix in c#.  Does math.net numerics have a matrix object whereby I can pass input values and extract a value from the matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Begin here at [Matrices and Vectors](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Matrix.html).